# jboss error in myeclipse - Connections refused

Tags: java, jboss

javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to server localhost:1099 [Root exception is
    javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server localhost:1099 [Root exception is 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]]

I am new to jboss. i am using myeclipse 7.5. i have connected jboss in myeclipse and successfully deployed and runs the project. its working without getting any problem till i shutdown my system. once my system is shutdown or restarted manually means i am getting the above problem.

i need the reason and solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate reason is that nothing is listening for connections on 127.0.0.1 port 1099.

You need to elaborate on what you mean by "my system is shutdown or restarted manually", but I suspect that whatever you are doing to shut down / restart is not restarting JBoss correctly.  Check using `ps` to see if JBoss is running, and look at the JBoss log files.

Another possibility is that this is something to do with your using "localhost" / 127.0.0.1 to run / access JBoss.  127.0.0.1 uses the loopback interface, and means that a client on one machine won't to be able to connect to the server on another machine.  (But, if you are just testing things on one machine, this won't matter.)